# Django Celery Multiple Workers and Multiple Queues

Tags: django, multithreading, rabbitmq, celery

I have 5 workers named 1-5 and two queues A and B, I need to assign queue A for workers 1 and 2, and 3,4,5 dedicated for B, also I need to allocate workers 1 and 2 for the tasks in queue B, when A is empty or 1,2 in idle.

I need to configure this in my Celery tasks using RabbitMQ brocker from Django app.

Can you specify how to assign queue specific tasks and run worker according to the above logic?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

So, for celery this is what you need :

```
celery multi start 5 -A conf -l info -Q:1-2 queueA -Q:3-5 queueB --pidfile="%n.pid"
```

For assigning queue in django you have more than one method :
(my settings is in conf)
By tasks app/folder in settings :

```
app.conf.task_routes = {
    'appA.tasks.*': {'queue': 'queueA'},
    'appB.tasks.*': {'queue': 'queueB'},
}
```

Using directly :

```
myTask.apply_async((2, 2), queue='queueA', countdown=10)
```

And maybe some other, but for me i use this method :

```
app.conf.task_default_queue = 'queueA'
```

And i use `app.conf.task_routes` for specific use like cron